# Using aws cli to convert provisioned database to aurora serverless v2

Tags: aws-aurora-serverless

Does anyone know if its possible to migrate a provisioned DB to a aurora serverless V2 DB using aws cli?

I am trying to script the answer in this question: [Upgrading from AWS Aurora Serverless v1 to v2 fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71989063/upgrading-from-aws-aurora-serverless-v1-to-v2-fails/71989216#71989216)

And I am stuck on steps 8,9 and 10.

I have searched online and only found solutions using the console.